# Punning Inference seems not working in graphdb

Tags: rdf, owl, semantics, ontology, graphdb

I loaded in a repository of GraphDB the following statements:

```
@prefix foo: <http://fopo.com#> .
@prefix bar: <http://dd.com#> .

foo:Car a owl:Class .

foo:Animal a owl:Class ;
owl:disjointWith foo:Car .

foo:isEndangered a owl:ObjectProperty ;
rdf:domain foo:Animal ;
rdf:range bar:SomeSpecies .

foo:Ape a owl:Class ;
foo:isEndangered bar:SomeSpecies .
```

If I'm not wrong, since OWL2 introduced the [punning](http://wiki.opensemanticframework.org/index.php/Metamodeling_in_Domain_Ontologies) (i.e., using the same IRI of a Class for an individual for metamodelling), the following statements should be inferred:

```
foo:Ape a foo:Animal .
```

But it doesn't happen. I tried also different repositories settings without luck.

Is there a way to get that kind of inferences or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You are correct about the inferrence, but what do you mean by "it doesn't happen"? The fact that something logically follows from premises does not mean that something has to "happen". Can you explain more what you did and what you expect?

Comment: @AntoineZimmermann I expected to see the inferred axiom in the KB (graphdb has an embedded reasoner), but it was not there.

Comment: `rdfs:domain`, not `rdf:domain`.

Comment: And `rdfs:range`:D

Comment: @superciccio14 how do you check for the data? Do you use a SPARQL query? If so, it should work once you fixed the issues with the wrong prefix for domain and range

Comment: After replacing `rdf:domain` with `rdfs:domain`, it works both in Visual graph mode and in SPARQL mode. In SPARQL mode, be sure that second `>` in `>>` is not dotted. It works under RDFS and OWL-Max "rulesets" (I've not checked others).  BTW, due to OWL 2 DL punning, your data is just non-invalid or non-inconsistent under OWL rulesets. The statement you need is inferred due to [`rdfs2`](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#patterns-of-rdfs-entailment-informative) RDFS pattern.

Comment: @StanislavKralin This comment is complete enough to be an answer

Comment: @superciccio14 punning is allowed but it does not grant inferences. The inference you're after comes from the domain declaration.

Comment: Perfect guys. Thank you! If you want to add the answer, I'll mark it as the accepted!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just replace this statement:

```
foo:isEndangered rdf:domain foo:Animal .
```

with this:

```
foo:isEndangered rdfs:domain foo:Animal .
```

After replacing, `foo:Ape a foo:Animal` should be inferred:

- [Visual Graph mode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhc46.png),
- [SPARQL mode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZf0X.png).

In SPARQL mode, be sure that the second `>` in the `>>` icon is not dotted, otherwise click the icon.

It works for me under RDFS and OWL-Max rulesets, I have not checked other ones.

---

As @Ignazio has said, OWL 2 DL punning does not grant inferences, the purpose of punning is rather opposite. OWL 2 DL punning allows entities to be classes and individuals simultaneously without considering an ontology being inconsistent (i. e. full of inferences) or invalid.

OWL punning is just a small part of total RDF(S) [freedom](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#rdfs-interpretations):

> RDFS does not partition the universe into disjoint categories of
>   classes, properties and individuals. Anything in the universe can be
>   used as a class or as a property, or both, while retaining its status
>   as an individual which may be in classes and have properties. Thus,
>   RDFS permits classes which contain other classes, classes of
>   properties, properties of classes, etc.

Actually, the inference you need is granted by the [`rdfs2`](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#patterns-of-rdfs-entailment-informative) RDFS entailment pattern.

---

I hope the mnemonic table below would be helpful. It shows which term mentioned in the RDFS vocabulary is of which prefix.

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|       rdfs:        |      rdf:      |
+--------------------+----------------+
|                Classes              |
+--------------------+----------------+
| rdfs:Resource      | rdf:Property   |
| rdfs:Class         | rdf:langString |
| rdfs:Literal       | rdf:HTML       |
| rdfs:Datatype      | rdf:XMLLiteral |
+--------------------+----------------+
|               Properties            |
+--------------------+----------------+
| rdfs:range         | rdf:type       |
| rdfs:domain        |                |
| rdfs:subClassOf    |                |
| rdfs:subPropertyOf |                |
| rdfs:label         |                |
| rdfs:comment       |                |
+--------------------+----------------+
|             Other Vocabulary        |
+--------------------+----------------+
| rdfs:Container     | rdf:Bag        |
| rdfs:member        | rdf:Seq        |
| rdfs:seeAlso       | rdf:Alt        |
| rdfs:isdDefinedBy  | rdf:List       |
|                    | rdf:first      |
|                    | rdf:rest       |
|                    | rdf:nil        |
|                    | rdf:_1         |
|                    | rdf:Statement  |
|                    | rdf:subject    |
|                    | rdf:predicate  |
|                    | rdf:object     |
|                    | rdf:value      |
+--------------------+----------------+
```

P.S. Even if the statement you need is not inferred, this is [not a bug](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_domainrange):

> For example, while an RDF vocabulary can assert that an `author`
>   property is used to indicate resources that are instances of the class
>   `Person`, it does not say whether or how an application should act in
>   processing that range information. Different applications will use
>   this information in different ways. For example, data checking tools
>   might use this to help discover errors in some data set, an
>   interactive editor might suggest appropriate values, and a reasoning
>   application might use it to infer additional information from instance
>   data.

:-)

Comment: Great answer Stanislav! : ) In other words, when we use punning in OWL2, resources are strictly divided in ABox an TBox without any fuzziness. No matter the double IRI usage. OWL Inference works as usual.